# What does "the young go getters" mean?

Tags: colloquialisms, collocation

I came across this colloquial phrase: "the young go getters". What does that actually mean? Does it refer to a young child/adolescent who is supposed to be a creative thinker?

Comment: It refers to an energetic and ambitious young person (of any age) and it should be hyphenated: "go-getter".

Comment: It's go-getter, with a hyphen. Look it up. Voting to close this as it's gen-ref

Comment: Welcome to ELU, "a student." When you get a moment click on this [Link](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and take the site TOUR, and also click on the HELP button on the right-side of the title-bar and check–out the “HELP CENTER,” if you haven’t already done so. There’s a lot to learn about this place, such as how to ask good questions and provide good answers, all about rep points and the site privileges they confer. It’s well worth looking around. Anyway, enjoy yourself, and we’ll see you around.

Answer (score 1):

A *go-getter* is someone with energy and drive, who really goes after what they want. They are prepared to work hard to achieve their goals. You don't have to be young to be a go-getter, but I guess it's something more associated with young people, ie. people who are on the way up career/success-wise.

Answer (score 0):

If Joe wants something, he goes and gets it. Joe is a go-getter.

A [*go-getter*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/go-getter) is hardworking and ambitious. *Young* is not typically associated with the idiom: it's just a modifier in that sentence.